# Issue with webpack in production mode ( minification issue )

Tags: javascript, webpack, augmented-reality, artoolkit, jsartoolkit

I am working on this little project for Augmented Reality, [**ARnft**](https://github.com/kalwalt/ARnft) it is based on a lighter version of Jsartoolkit5, [**JsartoolkitNFT**](https://github.com/kalwalt/jsartoolkitNFT) for only **NFT** markers. The code follows the **ES6** standard (partially) and use webpack as bundler. All is fine in development mode but when i go in production mode, the example stuck with this error:

```
05ff8846-4121-4380-86c3-9612f404732a:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name
```

It stop at the embedded Worker. The app don't enter inside because i otherwise i will receive some messages in the dev console. 
I Inject the Worker in a Blob object:

```js
// create a Worker to handle loading of NFT marker and tracking of it
const workerBlob = new Blob(
  [workerRunner.toString().replace(/^function .+\{?|\}$/g, '')],
    { type: 'text/js-worker' }
  )
const workerBlobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(workerBlob)

worker = new Worker(workerBlobUrl)
```

https://github.com/kalwalt/ARnft/blob/8322585aa0f863917c6d1cee541356ff3b7c36a0/src/utils/Utils.js#L207-L213

workerRunner defined at this line:

https://github.com/kalwalt/ARnft/blob/8322585aa0f863917c6d1cee541356ff3b7c36a0/src/utils/Utils.js#L272

I think that is a minification issue i tried to add `--optimize-minimize` in the script:

```
"build-es6": "webpack --mode production --optimize-minimize",
```

, but not helped. How can i solve this?

Thank you

Comment: This is probably a bug with the minifier. Try to narrow down the problem and then submit a bug report.

Comment: @D.Pardal thank you, i will try it!

Comment: with: 'webpack --mode production --optimize-minimize -d' the Blob Worker is loaded and the example works. The problem is in this function workerRunner on how is handled by  the minifier. I will open an issue in the webpack repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be solved with the [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader) plugin.

Instead of inlining the worker in a Blob as explained in the question:

- create an external Worker.js and import in the file (in this case Utils.js):

```js
import Worker from './Worker.js'
```

- use the worker as usual:

```js
let worker
// other code
worker = new Worker()
// other code with postMessage and onmesssage...
```

- in wepback.config.js

```js
{
  test: /\worker\.js$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'worker-loader',
        options: { inline: true, fallback: false }
    }
}
```

You can also see this [commit](https://github.com/kalwalt/ARnft/commit/6f95c6476f7e0cdcd41220dbb1c83cab813e0205) and the issue on [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10778).